# C# OutOfMemoryException when multiple threads are inserting data into a list with same time lag

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I met a weird phenomenon when threads (started at almost the same time) sleep a same and fixed time before inserting data, the exception occurs. But if they each sleeps a random time before inserting data, no exception about memory will occur. This happens repeatably.

The list had no more than 2000 items (each of them is about only 10 bytes) when it crashed every time. This seems not exceeding the memory limit.

if each thread sleeps like this:

```
Thread.Sleep((int)((new Random(DateTime.Now.Second)).NextDouble() * 10000));
```

it will not make app crashed, while if sleeping a same & fixed time:

```
Thread.Sleep(6000);
```

it will crash.

UPDATE:
sorry for the incomplete information and thanks for your answers.
I DO have a locker while editing the list (whenever and wherever).

And I replaced the "sleeping" with my real time-consuming work (obviously with different finishing time), the OutOfMemory exception never occurred again.

So here is the abstracted problem:
some threads (about 30) start at a same time (almost) and sleep for the same time and then do something with a list (with lock) at the same time (almost). It will cause OutOfMemoryException.
But if let it be less simultaneous (sleep/do jobs for different time), it will be OK.

Yes the high simultaneity will cause some problems but why OutOfMemory? Only 30 threads and each of them updating only several bytes to a list.
Thanks.

Sorry the stack tracing info is lost. :(

Comment: Please post the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: If you want to create pseudo random numbers you should create a single instance of the `Random` class and then repeatedly call `NextDouble`. The numbers your code generate will only change each second.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryException`? What type of list are you using? `List<T>`? What is `T` (the element type)? In particular is `T` a value or reference type? How do you add elements to the list? How many threads are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is multiple threads are accesing the same element at the same time and this causes unpredictable errors. To syncronize threads try this

```
lock(yourListObject)
{
   yourListObject.InsertData(data);
}
```

EDIT: You should look at [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: sorry for the incomplete info. i do have locking mechanism in code. i just feel strange why our of memory exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The list type you are using is not thread safe. You can make your adding and access code thread safe or use a thread safe list type. Without code (type) it is hard to say what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is something in your inserting code that causes a high memory load, when all threads try to update the list simultaneously. Maybe some locking mechanism? Or any recursions or loops that try to insert data into a possibly locked resource?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete info. please check the updated question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of List to see if your problem comes from concurrent access on your list.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I should consider about thread-safe data structures. but I am mostly curious about why out of memory exception.